# Insert Data into db but show it as a list using Laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

I can insert data into database but I want to show it as a List. But I don't understand how can I do it. I just stack here doing a project. how can i solve this problem ? please help. Advance Thanks.

This is my Controller Code:

```
  public function courseDetails($id)
    {
    $courseByID = DB::table('courses')
                ->join('course_outlines','course_outlines.course_id','=','courses.id' )
                ->where('courses.id',$id)
                ->select('courses.*','course_outlines.title1','course_outlines.class1')
                ->first();
    return view('frontEnd.pages.courseDetails',['courseByID'=>$courseByID]);
    }
```

This is my View code:

```
 <div class="card" >
    <div class="card-body">
         <h2  class="">Course Outline</h2>
         <div class="outline_section">
             <h4><span class="outline_header">{{$courseByID->title1}}</span></h4>
             <ul>
                <li>{{$courseByID->class1}}</li>
             </ul>
         </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to show like this but using just 1 row ..

[image]

`dd($courseByID)` result :
[image: ![enter image description here]

```
{#386 ▼
  +"id": 60
  +"course_name": "In a vero pariatur."
  +"trainer_name": "Ward Jaskolski"
  +"tution_fee": "25590"
  +"duration": "9"
  +"total_student": null
  +"total_class": "11"
  +"batch_no": "9"
  +"shift": "day"
  +"type": "short"
  +"hours": "112"
  +"start_date": "1979-11-02"
  +"deadline": "1998-12-24"
  +"status": "1"
  +"created_at": null
  +"updated_at": null
  +"title1": "HTML & CSS"
  +"class1": """
    * PC De-assembly and Assembly,
    * Bus Architecture & Interfaces,
    * BIOS, Processor & Motherboard,
     * Operating Systems and Installation (Windows XP/7, Ubuntu), Partitioning & Formatting Hard Disk,
    * Laptop De-assembly and Assembly,
    * Installing adapters,
    * Computer Networking Fundamentals,
    * Networking Media & Hardware,
     * Diagnostics and Troubleshooting
    * Sharing file within LAN
    """
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code, please

Comment: I update  my question please check it and kindly help for doing this. This code show like a Paragraph.

Comment: Debug first, what do you get if you ```dd($courseByID)``` inside your courseDetails methods

Comment: I updated sir .please check

Comment: I can't see your image, please share your result

Comment: I share it, sir.

Comment: If you ```dd($courseByID->class1)``` is return array ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223315/discussion-between-mm-chanchal-and-encang-cutbray).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
<div class="card" >
  <div class="card-body">
     <h2  class="">Course Outline</h2>
     <div class="outline_section">
        <h4><span class="outline_header">{{$courseByID->title1}}</span></h4>
        <ul>
          @foreach(str_replace(['""','*'],['',''], explode(",",$courseByID->class1)) as $key => $val)
            <li>{{ $val }}</li>
          @endforeach     
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above code tested **[here](https://rextester.com/RPZ19485)**